# Convert CSV File to txt file in Python with comma

Tags: python, excel, csv

I would like to convert the following csv file to a  txt file.

[image: CSV File]

```
import csv
csv_file = (r'symbols/Input_weekly_insidebar.csv')
txt_file = (r'symbols/Input_weekly_insidebar.txt')
with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
   with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
     [ my_output_file.write(','.join(row)) for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)]
 
     
my_output_file.close()
```

In the txt output file each symbol should have a comma ',' after the symbol.
Result should be:
[image]

Could you tell me what is wrong in my code? Because the above code produce an output without commas.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You are not joining rows together.  Your list comprehension should be ***inside*** your `join()`.

Comment: Can you post an example,please?

Comment: Untested: `my_output_file.write(',', join([ row for row in csv.reader(my_input_file)])`

Comment: I get an error Syntax Fault

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all rows only contain a single element, no separator will be inserted by `','.join(row)`.
One simple way to fix it is to just pick the first and only element of each row, which is `row[0]`.

I throw in a `next(reader)` in order to skip the csv header.

```py
import csv

csv_file = r'symbols/Input_weekly_insidebar.csv'
txt_file = r'symbols/Input_weekly_insidebar.txt'
with open(txt_file, "w") as my_output_file:
    with open(csv_file, "r") as my_input_file:
        reader = csv.reader(my_input_file)
        next(reader)  # skip the header
        my_output_file.write(','.join(row[0] for row in reader))
```

Please note that you should not manually call `my_output_file.close()` because you are already using a `with` statement to open your files. The `with` statement closes the files for you already.